# PySpark - Can't concat two elements from the same RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, pyspark, rdd

I've a RDD (data) with the following elements: first_name, last_name, technology

```
[u'Army', u'Dall', u'java']
[u'Fredy', u'Monty', u'C']
[u'John', u'Cabral', u'R']
[u'Mathy', u'Gauld', u'Python']
```

What I'm trying to get is:

```
[u'Army Dall', u'java']
[u'Fredy Monty', u'C']
[u'John Cabral', u'R']
[u'Mathy Gauld', u'Python']
```

In order to get this I'm trying with:

```
data.glom().map(lambda line: (line[0]+ " " + line[1])).collect()
```

However I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason you need to call `glom` on your data? Remove `glom`, and it should work.

Comment: right :) it works